# std::cout with constexpr on templated function works. Why?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
constexpr void f(T) { std::cout << ""; } // compiles

constexpr void g(int) { std::cout << ""; } // does not compile

int main() {
    f(1);
}
```

Why `f` compiles and `g` does not?

Used GCC 9.1 and Clang 8.0

Comment: Also reproduced on Visual C++ 14.0.

Comment: Tell me if the dupe is wrong. But the issue, and the reason why is exactly the same, and the answer is the same as far as I know

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I believe that the dupe is accurate. `g` is also invalid but no diagnostic is required.

Comment: One paragraph down, but ill-formed NDR just the same.

Comment: Looks like the duplicate was asked by this question's OP less than a day ago. If the first answer to your question wasn't satisfactory, please be more specific as to what you found problematic with it.

Comment: I was satisfied with the last answer. But now I have templates. Can I consider then thats a compiler problem? In the last question, Clang detected all the problems, but now I can say that the templated one is too complex for it evaluate?